# Deploy helm chart from remote repository

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to run a deployment job that downloads helm chart from bitbucket repository and applies the helm chart into kubernetes:

```
pipeline {
    agent  any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
    
                 script {
                    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'my_kubeconfig']) {
                        sh '''
                        helm upgrade --install // download and install helm chart here                           
             
                        '''
                    }
                 }
                
            }
        }
    } //
}
```

If possible I want first to download the helm chart from bitbucket repository and then using kubernetes service account to apply the chart.

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if any of below answer resolves you issues or do share your solution if manage to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right first need to clone the Helm template repo build the files

You can review this file although i am not using Helm but mostly steps are similar might need to do last step **tweaks** : https://github.com/harsh4870/node-js-aws-codebuild-basic-ci-cd/blob/main/Jenkinsfile